# Installing packages android studio (recyclerview for example)

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, package

Good day everyone

As the title suggests I would like to know how to use packages in androids studio. I might have missed something, because I can't seem to find anything usefull on the internets neither here on Stackovervlow. (My apologies if I'm wrong)

The package I would like to use is:
package com.vogella.android.recyclerview;
I typed it (like this) on the top of the class where I want to use it. But it gives an error:
Package name 'com.vogella.android.recyclerview;' does not correspond to the file path '[insert path name]'.

I didn't install anything, because its not in the vogella tutorial for RecyclerViews.

I'm pretty new at this so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> package com.vogella.android.recyclerview;

That's the package name of the code used in the tutorial you're following. It's nothing that needs to be installed, packages are just a way to organize Java applications.

In your application it will be replaced by the package name of your app and it's generally automatically generated by Android Studio (or any other IDE for that matter).

Read how Java packages works: [Packages Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

As for your problem, the Vogella tutorial clearly states you've to to declare you want to use RecyclerView in your grade file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1"
}
```

Comment: Ooh okay now I get it! Thanks! 
Also, do you perhaps know where you have to declare it? Because I declared it in build.gradle Module:app and it seems to work, but you also have Project: 'appname'.
Also it said to make it compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
And otherwise it doens't work, do you know if it matters?
Thanks!!

Comment: please accept if it helped. I suggest you try a bit simpler things before this

Comment: Well yeah the problem is that I have to do this for school, I have never used this program.

Comment: Have you done any programming ever? if not, try understand how java works to start with, then the Android platform. You can also use other components instead of RecyclerView, ListView for example it's a little less difficult to write.